# Как работает опция serial?

Tags: ansible

Добрый вечер.

Интересует подробности работы опции **serial** для задач. Документация, как у всех современных инструментов, вызвает больше вопросов, чем отвечает на них.

Конфиг Ansible содержит:

для установки

```
forks = 100
strategy = linear
```

для сбора метрик

```
forks = 100
strategy = free
```

Число хостов до 3.000 с распределенным пингом и качеством канала (VPN тоннель)

Как повлияет **serial** на производительность и скорость выполнения плейбука?

Ansible: 2.4

Ссылки

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_strategies.html
- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опция `serial` заставляет Ansible разбить список хостов в текущей `play` на пачки.

Это описано здесь: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size

Например, для:

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial:
    - 1
    - 5
    - "20%"
```

все хосты по шаблону `webservers` будут разделены на группы размера `1`, `5`, и оставшиеся частями по `20%`.

Стратегия выполнения в таком случае подразумевает, что сначала выполнятся все задачи для одного хоста (размер пачки – 1), затем выполнятся все задачи для следующих пяти хостов (размер пачки – 5), затем будут выполнятся группами по 20%.

Не очень понимаю, что вкладывается в термин «производительность», но скорость уменьшится, т.к. `serial` используется для «отключения» параллелизма. Это удобно использовать, к примеру, когда нужно обновить несколько одинаковых серверов за балансировщиком – исключить одновременное отключение всех рабочих инстансов. Или для проверочных прогонов – сначала на одном сервере проверить все таски, затем еще на парочке и потом параллельно все оставшиеся.

Comment: Для меня в данном контексте "производительность" - время отыгрывания роли на n хостах. Влияет ли на это **serial**  как например **strategy**?

Comment: Да, _"скорость уменьшится, т.к. serial используется для «отключения» параллелизма"_. Если нужно увеличить скорость, рекомендую заглянуть в [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/343368/) – возможно, какой-то из параметров вам поможет ускориться..

Comment: Да с нее начал оптимизацию, сейчас пробуют разные опции SSH, играю со strategy.  Приходится работать через большое количество фаерволов, например pipelining тормозит обработку для меня.